# Table '/tmp/#sql_1_0.MAI' is read only

Tags: mysql

When I try to use `SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM` or some other [SHOW COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html) syntax query I get this strange error message:

```
MariaDB [mysql]> show full fields from user;
ERROR 1036 (HY000): Table '/tmp/#sql_126_0.MAI' is read only
```

Tmp dir is present and has `777` permissions.
Changing tmp dir in `my.cnf` doesn't help.

`Chown`ing that dir to mysql user doesn't help either.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install CentOS 7 into VM (or any sufficiently old kernel)
2. Install Docker on CentOS 7 (so that we can use alpine)
3. Create alpine-based image with MariaDB 10.1.28 (`apk add mysql mysql-client`) or use readily available image
4. Run mysql container `docker run --name mariadb_container mariadb_image`
5. Connect to mysql using `docker exec -ti mariadb_container mysql -A`
6. Run `SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM some_table` query

Any suggestions on how to trace that problem?

Comment: To trace this problem I used `strace`. I've run it on both failing and succeeding reproduce steps. I've found out that the difference is the failing `readlink("/proc/self/fd/43"` syscall. This has lead me to [this issue](https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/7345). Googling `/proc` `readlink` issues has lead be [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/18883). After that I've tried to grep MariaDB source code, found [this patch made to 10.1.22](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/commit/b27fd90ad36f4194665744cc1dcdd05f2d0b47ef#diff-bc0905410089f46d3bc9a8331697da6a). And here we are.

Answer (score 4):

**Warning**: this is a working theory, not confirmed by any independent sources.

There are 3 points of failure that may explain why the bug is reproducible under the very specific conditions (`CentOS 7`, `docker`, `alpine`, `mariadb 10.1.22+`):

- some [linux kernel bug](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/18883) specific to `/proc/self/fd/%d` permissions for container threads and setuid
- `/proc/`-based  [`realpath` implementation](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/commit/src/misc/realpath.c?id=e98bdca9df8df791fe93ec8eec920fa8d14da1f5) in `musl` library
- changes in mariadb to fix [`mi_open` race condition security issue](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11902)

Links to discussions:

- [docker4drupal](https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal/issues/148)
- [Alpine mariadb package](https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/7345)
- [docker issue describing wrong `readlink` behavior](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/18883)
- [discussion of musl implementation of `realpath`](http://www.openwall.com/lists/musl/2016/06/07/1)

Links to code:

- [Kernel fix for fd permissions security issue](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/96d0df79f2644fc823f26c06491e182d87a90c2a) (2013, included in kernel `3.12+`)
- [Kernel fix to fix regression introduced by previous fix](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/54708d2858e79a2bdda10bf8a20c80eb96c20613) (2015, included in kernel `4.4+`)
- [realpath implementation in musl](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/commit/src/misc/realpath.c?id=e98bdca9df8df791fe93ec8eec920fa8d14da1f5)
- mi_open fix in mariadb

Approaches to fix:

- upgrade to the latest kernel version (no new versions available in CentOS/RHEL, so switch to another OS or make a petition to RedHat to backport [the fix](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/54708d2858e79a2bdda10bf8a20c80eb96c20613))
- investigate issues in `musl` [`realpath` implementation](https://github.com/esmil/musl/blob/master/src/misc/realpath.c)
- investigate issues in [mariadb `mi_open` implementation](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/b27fd90ad36f4194665744cc1dcdd05f2d0b47ef/storage/myisam/mi_open.c) (specifically changes to this file in 10.1.22)

Workarounds:

- Use glibc-based mariadb published on DockerHub: https://hub.docker.com/r/library/mariadb/tags/
- Switch to mariadb 10.1.20 (latest stable version before the bug): https://hub.docker.com/r/sizmek/mariadb/tags/

Answer (score 0):

You should try to downgrade your **Mariadb** to version **10.1.17** (worked for me)

Comment: It looks like the issue appeared somewhere between 10.1.21 and 10.1.22. 10.1.19 didn't have the issue